# Add text on video in ffmpeg on portrait video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am adding text on a portrait video in ffmpeg using following command:-

```
-i /sdcard/Hyype/195_Video.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontsize=80:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=Post:x=286.0:y=573.0-ascent -strict -2 /sdcard/Hyype/495_Edited_Video.mp
```

**This Command add text on video in landscape mode as shown in current output pic**

Following are screen shots :- 
1. Current output:-

[image]

2. Expected Output :-

[image]

Can someone help me that how can i add text on video in portrait form and achieve the expected output in second pic?

Comment: The input video is stored rotated, and a rotation tag fixes it during playback. You need to apply the [transpose](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#transpose) filter before the text to orient it correctly for drawtext. Also, remove the rotation tag `-metadata:s:v rotate=0`

Comment: I used following command:-  /sdcard/Hyype/585_Video.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontsize=80:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=Post:x=286.5:y=276.5 -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -strict -2 /sdcard/Hyype/990_Edited_Video.mp4                  But it is also rotating the video and text position on x,y co-ordinates is not also correct

Comment: You have to apply transpose filter before drawtext.

Comment: Now i used this command       -i /sdcard/Hyype/845_Video.mp4  -vf -metadata:s:v rotate=0 drawtext=fontsize=80:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=Post:x=326.0:y=429.5 -strict -2 /sdcard/Hyype/495_Edited_Video.mp4.  Still its providing same result

Comment: can u suggest me a command

Comment: -i /input.mp4 -vf transpose=2,drawtext=fontsize=80:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=P‌​ost:x=326.0:y=429.5 -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -strict -2 output.mp4 - you'll have to experiment with different values for transpose (from 0 to 3)

Comment: thanxx for help bro. Its working. Now only problem i am facing is that Text is not On Proper Position. Can u give me any idea?

Comment: Paste command and console readout and output screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109438/discussion-between-dhanveer-thakur-and-mulvya).